# Barriers to or barriers for

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say

> The barriers for enrollment are the long lines, long applications, and expensive travel fees.

Or

> The barriers to enrollment are the long lines, long applications, and expensive travel fees.

Or can you say it either way?

Comment: I prefer barriers to. If you go to Google Ngram and do a comparison between the two, it shows that barriers to is more common

Comment: The barriers for enrolment = The barriers for **the purpose of** enrolment -- The barriers to enrolment = The barriers **that are associated with** enrolment

Comment: This is a good place for a noun compound. _Enrollment barriers_ will normally be interpreted metaphorically, not physically.

Comment: Makes sense! Does it stick out too much either way? I accidentally used barriers for enrollment in a paper.